# 5V Voltage Regulation from Arduino

Tags: arduino, power-supply, circuit-design, voltage-regulator

A question about using the +5V supply pin from Arduino devices such as the Uno. Supplying my system (consists of sensors, ADCs, and opamps) using only this +5V supply pin, I'd like to regulate this voltage supply using a voltage regulator (TL431BVDG).

Being quite new to circuit design, will this connection to the voltage regulator be functional in providing a steady supply?

- TL431BVDG Voltage Regulator (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/TL431_D-2320199.pdf)
- 0.1uF Bypass Capacitors (https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/kemet/C0805C104J3RACTU/2211735)
- +5V on the right of the schematic is connected to the rest of my system
- +5V on the left of the schematic is connected to the +5V pin on an Arduino

[image: Schematic Capture]

Comment: The TL431 is a voltage reference not a voltage regulator.  They're typically used to provide a very stable fixed voltage that's used as a reference point by other circuitry and the currents involved are very low.  The Arduino has a regulator onboard so adding a downstream regulator is redundant and rather more complicated due to the fact that most regulators will have a "drop out voltage" of a few hundred mV to a few V between the input and output that they require to function.  How much current is the rest of your circuitry going to draw?

Comment: @vir I am using 5V as the reference voltage for my ADC, so its accuracy will depend on the accuracy of the 5V from the Arduino. Isn't this not very accurate and noisy because I am drawing current from the Arduino? The goal is to achieve a clean noise-free reference

Comment: In that case, I would use a 2.5V reference since the 5V regulator will not be able to help if your 5V supply dips.  Edit: @bobflux beat me to the 4.096V reference.

Comment: You can use a 3V3 or 4.096V LDO or reference from the arduino 5V to get a clean voltage for your ADC. Since these chips can't boost voltage, you can't use them to make 5V from a "5V" that could actually be 4.9V... You have to use a lower voltage.

Comment: It's a common voltage, but was more of a brain fart since 4.096 should be easier all around.

Comment: The schematic isn't using TL431 properly. TL431 is a shunt regulator, like a zener. It's not a series regulator, like a LDO. Basically, it depends on what you have available and if you're willing to pay $20 shipping for a 50c chip.

Comment: @bobflux Thank you so much once again. To confirm, the connection from the Arduino pin to the cathode pin of the TL431, grounding 3/4 of the anode pins on the TL431, and supplying the rest of my system using 1/4 of the anode pins on the TL431 is the correct configuration?

Comment: Basically what's your situation? Hobbyist and you want to get it done with the stuff you have in the parts bin, and there's a TL431 laying around?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you know this, but just to be clear: whichever reference voltage you choose should go to the AREF pin alone; powering your Arduino from your analog reference defeats the purpose.

Comment: Tip: it would be much easier for you and us if you used the TL431 [symbol](https://www.bristolwatch.com/ccs/TL431A2.htm) as that shows the *schema* of the device. What you've drawn is really a wiring diagram and it's very difficult to figure out voltages and current flow from the diagram whereas it's quite straightforward with the symbol or the diagram showing the expanded internals. This can often help avoid errors in wiring and layout.

Comment: @bobflux Using the TL431, how can I regulate the +5V from the Arduino?

Comment: You can't regulate it to 5V but you could make something like 4V. [check page 25](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1633760026015)

Comment: @bobflux Got it. Just a final question, if I were to use the +5V voltage pin of the Arduino and connect it directly to the reference voltage pin of my ADC, I should face no problems in the accuracy because the Arduino has an internal regulator for the +5V pin? For the ADC, I only require a +5V reference voltage for the LSB size.

Comment: Measurement will be as accurate as the arduino regulator, so that's usually around 5%. If that's alright, then go for it. You can add a RC filter like a few hundred ohms and a 470µF electrolytic cap to remove noise.